# typescript - prevent multiple test coverage

Tags: typescript, testing, code-coverage

I have in my project:
unit tests
integration tests
cypress tests
automation tests

I feel that there're a lot of tests that test the same code, how can I find these tests? and can I know for each code line with test test it? we're already using sonarcloud.
and how can I save time one test maintenance?

Thanks

Comment: You can use a coverage tool to show what lines of code are executed by what tests, exactly how this works depends on your test framework. ***However*** just because a line of code is executed during a test does not mean the line was actually tested (coverage only tells you what has not been tested) and the same line can be tested in different ways. You'll always have some overlapping tests, and that's a good thing. If your real goal is reducing test maintenance or improving test speed, there are better options, but we'd need to know more about your project.